# What is it Called When You Debug the Non-IIS Express Version of ASP.Net Core?

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

In ASP.Net core, there are two ways of running/debugging the app, IIS Express and ________?

I don't think it is proper to call the other way Kestrel b/c that is running in the IIS Express version, isn't it?

When I pick the green underlined option, what is that called?

Is dotnet hosting Kestrel then?

[image: Debugging ASP.Net Core]

Comment: I dont think Kestrel needs IIS express. If you run your project thru the command prompt with "dotnet run"; you won't see IIS express at all

Comment: Self-Host or just Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tratcher says: `ConsoleHost` would be a good term. Since your application is run with a shell around it which is called the `console` on windows. Which is the Host of your dotnet application.

If you want to be as appropriate as possible towards the red line `IIS express` which would be the host of the dotnet app, then `Console` would be the most appropriate, since its the host of the application.

Although in more OS independent terms its either called the shell or the terminal (console is a very windows term). But since visual studio only currently runs on windows that should be fine.